# Scala unused expression error with if statement

Tags: scala

I'm very new to Scala, and tried to write a simple Scala program that gets the maximum value. I found something weird (probably a language-specific feature). Here it is:

```
  def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
    if (xs.isEmpty) {
      throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException
    }

    def maxAux(x: List[Int], curMax: Int): Int = {
      if (x.isEmpty)  {
        curMax
      }
      if (x.head > curMax) {
        maxAux(x.tail, x.head)
      }
      else {
        maxAux(x.tail, curMax)
      }
    }
    maxAux(xs.tail, xs.head)
  }
}
```

For some reason, inside of `maxAux` function, the return of the first `if` statement gives me an IntelliJ warning that it is an "unused expression". Turns out it is correct because that line doesn't seem to return. To get around that issue, the second if statement in `maxAux` I changed to an `else if`, and then everything worked as intended. The other fix would be to add a `return` statement before `curMax`, but apparently using `return` is bad style/practice.

TL;DR: Can anyone explain why in the code above `curMax` doesn't return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate problem is that Scala returns the value of the last expression in a block which is the second `if`/`else` expression. So the value of the first `if` is just discarded. This can be fixed by making the second `if` an `else if` so that it is a single expression.

A better solution is to use `match`, which is the standard way of unpicking a `List`:

```
def maxAux(x: List[Int], curMax: Int): Int =
  x match {
    case Nil =>
      curMax
    case max :: tail if max > curMax =>
      maxAux(tail, max)
    case _ :: tail =>
      maxAux(tail, curMax)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In `def maxAux`, the control-flow can enter the first if-branch, whose body yields `curMax`. But that `if`-statement is not the last statement in `maxAux`, another `if`- or `else`-branch will follow, and they determine the result.

If you test your function (note that your code currently doesn't compile!), e.g. via `println(max(List(1,3,2,5,0)))`, then you'll get a `NoSuchElementException`, which is a consequence of your current (incorrect) implementation.

You have various options now, e.g. the following two, which only minimally change your code:

1. Fix the if-else cascade (which you could also rewrite into a pattern matching block):

   ```
   if (x.isEmpty)  {
     curMax
   } else if (x.head > curMax) {
     maxAux(x.tail, x.head)
   } else {
    maxAux(x.tail, curMax)
   }
   ```
2. Use a `return` statement (though you should be careful with the use of `return` in Scala. See the comments under this answer):

   ```
   if (x.isEmpty)  {
     return curMax
   }
   ```

Comment: Please don't use `return` unless you know what it does, which is probably not what you think it does.

Comment: @Tim Please elaborate

Comment: If you don't know what `return` does, see [this](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html) or [this](https://blog.knoldus.com/scala-best-practices-say-no-to-return/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Matte, you really cleared it up. I also agree with Tim after reading his resources. Return can be used here to solve the problem, but it should be noted the potential side effects of using it in other cases, as its likely more beginners will stumble upon this question and use return in incorrect ways.

Comment: @Tim See https://github.com/databricks/scala-style-guide#return for when to *prefer* return statements: it matches this case exactly. The Scala compiler & SDK also use return statements in such cases. If you don't know when to use `return`, maybe don't rush to comments so hastily.

Comment: That is one style guide for one platform. By contrast, the online course given by the author of the language deducts style points for using `return`, which is good enough for me. Also, you might want to actually use `return` in your answer.

Comment: @Tim Thanks, I've added the missing `return`. That was rather ... embarrassing. Regarding style guides: the official Scala style guide does not mention `return` at all (but they also don't use it); the Databricks one is fairly well known and clearly explains when & why `return` is to be avoided (closures) and when it is to be preferred. Lastly, if `return` is so bad, why do the Scala compiler & SDK implementers use it?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, it is good now. 
The problem with `return` is that it may have hidden consequences and can usually be replaced by a more "pure" functional coding style. The libraries use a lot of non-functional features (e.g. mutable data, `while` loops) in order to improve efficiency. (Which is, of course, an indictment of the ability of Scala to implement functional code in an efficient way, though this is often the fault of the JVM rather than Scala itself).